# Linux - Can cron run a script only when a specified application is running?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I want to run a script every 5 seconds, but (to conserve resources) only when a specified application is running. Is there a way to do that with crontab?

Comment: Use a wrapper which modifies crontab to call the application?

Answer (score 2):

There was similiar question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/800/how-to-run-scripts-every-5-seconds

Cron minimum is 1 minute. If you want less, you have to construct script with infinite loop and 'sleep 5'. And you may check if your specified application is running with pgrep. Like:

```
pgrep YOURAPP > /dev/null 2>&1 && YOURSHELL.sh
```

---

Example:

Let's say the script you want to run is /tmp/test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ >> /tmp/pids
```

we can run it if there is some ssh running every 5 seconds like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        pgrep ssh > /dev/null 2>&1 && /tmp/test2.sh
        sleep 5
done
```